# Create and append multiple files at once in a newly created Dir

Tags: python, file, datetime, mkdir

I have a data file which is to be splited date wise. Later I find the time difference of 2 columns i.e. `col[2] col[3]`. I can very well get the results when I write a separate code for both. But now I have to write one code for splitting the data datewise and also calculate the time difference. Possibly both at same time. It only creates the dir and then gives the error below. How can I read the file and manipulate and again append them in same location and same file.

Input:

```
3545 3140 1736190 1736241
4602 183 1736227 1738507
3545 3140 1736241 1736257
4945 3545 1737037 1737370
4945 3545 1737387 1737661
4391 2814 1737629 1737645
4945 3545 1737661 1738047
5045 4921 1740400 1803478
5045 3545 1740832 1741728
4921 3545 1740832 1741728
5045 1683 1743140 1744248
4921 1683 1743140 1744248
5454 4391 1746616 1750777
5454 5070 1748022 1750777
5070 4391 1748022 1750957
1158 305 1749609 1749610
```

Code:

```
import os, sys
import itertools
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime

# Extract the date from the timestamp that is the third item in a line
# (Will be grouping by start timestamp)
if not os.path.isfile("testdir") and not os.path.isdir("testdir"):
        os.mkdir("testdir")
def key(s):
    return datetime.date.fromtimestamp(int(s.split()[2]))

with open('input.txt') as in_f:
    for date, group in itertools.groupby(in_f, key=key):
        # Output to file that is named like "1970-01-01.txt"    
        with open(os.path.join("testdir",'{:%Y-%m-%d}.txt'.format(date)),'w') as out_f:
                    out_f.writelines(group)

#Below we calculate the time epoch difference from col[2] col[3]

with open(os.path("testdir",'{:%Y-%m-%d}.txt'.format(date)),'a+') as a_f:
    for rows in a_f:
        node_one, node_two, time_epoch_one, time_epoch_two = line.split()
        epoch_datetime_one = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time_epoch_one))
        epoch_datetime_two = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time_epoch_two))
        contact_duraction_time = abs(mktime(epoch_datetime_one.timetuple()) - mktime(epoch_datetime_two.timetuple()))  
        duration = datetime.fromtimestamp(contact_duraction_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        a_f.write("%s %s %s\n" % (node_one, node_two, contact_duraction_time))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "time_split.py", line 15, in <module>
    for date, group in itertools.groupby(in_f, key=key):
  File "time_split.py", line 12, in key
    return datetime.date.fromtimestamp(int(s.split()[2]))
AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'fromtimestamp'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your import syntax. As you wrote

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
```

The second import (causing `datatime`:: `datetime.datetime`) hides the first, and you can no longer use `datatime.date` because it is read as `datetime.datetime.date`

You should either only use `import datetime` and (use `datetime.datetime` for subsequent uses of *class* `datetime`) or use `from datetime import datetime, date` and directly use `datetime`and `data` as class names. You function then becomes :

```
def key(s):
    return date.fromtimestamp(int(s.split()[2]))
```

Edit :

datetime is a module, and is also the name of a class of this module. It is not the best design in Python standard library, but I believe compatibility forces that now ... As a general rule **never** use `from datetime import datetime` (unless you are sure to not use any other class from the module ...)

Comment: I think I am seriously confused here.